# How to put main index entries in bold

Tags: indexing

I need to create an index for a technical document. I would like some index references to have the main entry (typically where a term is defined) in bold and all other references in the same index entry (typically where the term is simply used) in normal text. Is there an easy way to do that in Latex?

Comment: Maybe have a look at the `glossaries` package?

Comment: That seems to make a /separate/ glossary, rather than highlight entries in the main index. If the client discovers I can do that, I expect that will be the next job, but I want something *within* the main index (like the index in Don Knuth's original TexBook - that used underlines rather than bold, but that would be fine).

Comment: If you already have some code, it would be good if you could post a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows the set up you are currently working with. There are various indexing mechanisms to choose from.